# fftshift produces zero components

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, fft

I am trying to implement a 2D Fourier transform in an image and my code is:

```py
image = cv2.imread(str(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
f = np.fft.fft2(image)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))
```

Then in magnitude_spectrum I can see that one component is `-inf` which means that it is **0** in `fshift`. Why does this happen ?

I tried to apply this with other images and it worked, but some other images produce 0. So is this only image-dependent ?

Comment: Please provide the set of images that  produce different outputs to form a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `fftshift` only reorganizes the data, it doesn’t set any values to 0. You might have had the 0 in there before calling `fftshift`.